# How to get into Docker container's shell when bash is not available?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

HI recently downloaded mcandre/docker-java-slim and is trying to install a few java apps however I can't get into bash?  I think may be its not even installed.

```
 docker run -it --rm \
-v /home/ubuntu:/data --name test mcandre/docker-java-slim bash
```

the above command fails! Is there anything else I can do? thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a shell?  If you ran `java` directly, how would you do the equivalent operation on a JVM without a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash is not installed on this image but `sh` is so just do `docker run -it --rm -v /home/ubuntu:/data --name test mcandre/docker-java-slim sh`

Answer (score 1):

Since the base OS is Linux Alpine, it does not come with `bash`, but you can use either `sh` or `ash`.

Up to my knowledge, `sh` is pre-installed on the most of Linux Distros, so you can use `sh` as shell whenever you get fail with running `bash`.

Run either:

```
docker run -it --rm \
-v /home/ubuntu:/data --name test mcandre/docker-java-slim sh
```

or:

```
docker run -it --rm \
-v /home/ubuntu:/data --name test mcandre/docker-java-slim ash
```

to log in with shell.